# call_user_func_array() error after moving to another server

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, functions

I've just moved my WP site from one server to another and my custom post type plugin is causing the following error:

> **Warning:** call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_admin' not found or invalid function name in /var/sites/*/******.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 496

My code for the custom post types is as follows:

```
function all_post_types() {
    create_video_camera();
    create_stills_camera();
    create_lens();
    create_light();
    create_sound();
    create_aerial();
}

add_action( 'init', 'all_post_types' );

function create_video_camera() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Video Cameras', 'Post Type General Name', '******' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Video Camera', 'Post Type Singular Name', '******' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Video Camera', '******' ),
        'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Video Camera', '******' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Video Camera:', '******' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Video Cameras', '******' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Video Camera', '******' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', '******' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'New Video Camera', '******' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Video Camera', '******' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Video Camera', '******' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Video Camera', '******' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Video Camera', '******' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', '******' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', '******' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'video_camera', '******' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Video Camera Template', '******' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 25,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-video-alt',
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,      
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'video_camera', $args );

}
```

with the other register_post_type functions being largely similar.

It all worked perfectly on the old server, but now I'mm getting the error. I've tried other solutions, but with no luck.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you find a `my_admin` function anywhere in your code, or any references to it? Try looking across the entire codebase, not just the parts you've coded

Comment: As @TomJNowell suggests, the code above does not contain `my_admin` function calling, so there is no problem (in that particular code).

Comment: I do use the code `add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );` at the bottom of the file. It's weird, because I just copied everything across form the other server and it suddenly became a problem.

Comment: you should remove that then, unless there's a longer version on your old server with the definition of `my_admin`

Comment: I deleted it, and the custom post types dissipated. I changed it to `my_admin` to `all_post_types` and the error vanished. It all looks the same on the old server, so it must have been running off magic. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code contained the line `add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );` at the end, but `my_admin` wasn't declared anywhere. Changed it to `all_post_types`, my function to register all the custom post types at once and it worked.